# wamy project's R.java file is causing and error and when ever i fix it eclipse removes the changes i made

Tags: android, eclipse

this is causing the error

```
        public static final class id {
        public static final int timeToSend=0x7f080021;
        public static final int timeToSend,=0x7f080023;
        }
```

whenever I remove the second and save the file eclipse changes it back. I tried changing it while eclipse is not running and yet when I opened eclipse it changed the file back. I don't have any duplicates in layout to cause the problem. I tried cleaning the project and it didn't work.
turns out I wrote  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeToSend," instead of  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeToSend"  that's why it nade a duplicate with the comma. sorry for the trouble

Comment: the problem is the existing of duplicates and the comma in the second int

Comment: IDs must be unique. Try to call them timeToSend1 and timeToSend2. Also note that it's **very dangerous** to manually modify the R.java file!

Comment: Dont you ever modify R.java by yourself, is an automatically generated file

Comment: @FrankN.Stein the thing is I only have one timeTosend so I don't know why it made duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you have an XML element with the `android:id="@+id/timeToSend,"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Android ID's cannot have any special characters in them. So `android:id="@+id/timeToSend,` would be wrong due to the fact that it has a comma. All you have to do is find that ID and rename it.

It's not recommended to edit the R.java file because it generates itself based on all the ID's you have created. The only way to edit it is to get rid of the ID's that you have declared in XML, otherwise, every time you clean the project, they regenerate.

Comment: I don't have timeToSend, I only have one id called timeToSend so I don't know from where  the one with comma appeared

Comment: I wrote  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeToSend," instead of  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeToSend"  that's why it

Comment: Exactly what Andrew said.

Comment: So it's fixed? Good if it is!

Answer (score 0):

Something that I always try when R.java is giving me problems is rebuilding the project.

You should be able to find the option under **Project** and then **Clean**.
That's only if rebuilding it hasn't worked.

Good luck and I hope this helps!